# Why is my program refrenceing the readline command multiple times and how do I stop it

Tags: python-3.x

Okay. So I am trying to make a code which is basically a guess the word game. since it is for a school assignment there are certain required parts such as the used of 4 functions and those functions doing certain things. the program need to pull information off of an words sheet which is stored on an external .txt file. When I try to use a line from said using the readline command it will move to the next line every time I reference the function which leaves me in a pickle.

Here is the code

```
import random
#Variables
file = open('words.txt','r')
Number_of_lines = 0
Correct = 'Place holder'
Score = 0
#Retrieve the next word through readline command
def get_a_Word():
    Basic_Word = file.readline()
    Word = Basic_Word
    Word = Word
    return Word
#Turn the word into a guess word
def guess_Word():
    Word = get_a_Word()
    Edited_Word = '*' + Word[1:]
    return Edited_Word
def check_Word(Word):
    if Word == get_a_Word():
        return True
    else:
        return False
#Put that shit together
def Main():
    Line = 0
    while Line < 10:
        Edited_Word = guess_Word()
        Score = 0
        Line = Line + 1
        Word = input('Given {} What is the word? '.format(Edited_Word))
        Word = Word.upper()
        if check_Word(Word) == True:
            print('That is correct!')
            Score = Score + 10
        elif check_Word(Word) == False:
            print('That is incorrect. the word was {}.'.format(get_a_Word()))
        else:
            print('you broke it')
    Correct = Score/10
   print('You have successfully guessed {} out of 10 words. Your final score is {}.' .format(Correct, Score))
Main()
file.close()
```

The .txt File contains these word in this order 
Store
Apple
Bicycle
Water
Mercedes
Classroom
Architect
Elevator
Measurement
Godzilla

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint 1: get_a_Word() gets a new value from the list every time you call it. Hint 2: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how the functions you're supposed to have are specified, but the obvious solution to not getting multiple different words is simply not to call `get_a_Word` more than once per cycle of the main loop. Some of the other functions may need to be changed to take the previously fetched word as an argument.

The loop would look something like this (pseudocode, I may be skipping some things):

```
while line < 10:
    word = get_a_Word()
    edited_word = guess_Word(word)
    guess = input('Given {} What is the word? '.format(edited_word))
    if check_Word(word, guess):
        print('That is correct!')
        score += 10
    else:
        print('That is incorrect. The word was {}.'.format(word))
```

A note on naming, unrelated to your issue: Python convention for naming variables and functions is to use `lowercase_names_with_underscores` for everything, unless the code is mimicking an existing API that uses a different convention. Use `CapitalizedNames` for classes, and `ALL_CAPS` for constants.

The most important thing though, is to to be consistent. Your current code seems to have a mix of underscores, capitalization and other styles without any logic to it. Pick one style (even if it's not the one I described in the previous paragraph) and stick to it. (This can be hard to do if your instructor is inconsistent in naming style. Alas there may not be much you can do about that.)

Comment: Thank you for the information. The titles for the functions as well as what they do was required by the teacher. if it was my choice I would have gone about it in a different way but a grade is a grade.